# Manga: girl goes through a door leading to a prince, stacked books, and her appearance changes to a female version of the prince

Tags: story-identification, manga

I read this manga but I forgot to save my data on the app I found it on, and all my mangas were lost. I found all of them again except one and I don't remember the name and I only remember a little bit of it.

The manga was about a girl with brown hair who went to this place, where the receptionist told her to go through a door and wait in the room. The girl waited and when she walked out she was in a room filled with stacked books. In the room was a prince, who I think had red eyes and blonde hair. Another young man walked in and noticed her and asked who she was. When they finally were looking at her she looked exactly like the girl version of the prince.

Before they could do anything she went back through the door and she went back to the place where she was before; only she had her normal hair and eye color back. When they went to look for her they couldn't find her.

Comment: Hi there. That's a good start; but maybe you could take a look at [these guidelines on story-ID](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in? For instance, when would this have been published?

Comment: Also, what app was that on? And what hinted at the guy being a prince?

Comment: It was on manga rock and I think he had a crown

Comment: The manga was in English.

Answer (score 3):

This is [Living as the Emperor's Fiancée](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=150945).

> Adel, who entered the emperor's office due to the magic of the imperial magic, accidentally hears the secret plan of the emperor.

> 'Emperor,' 'fiancée,' 'fake,' 'killing,'… the interior minister and the emperor who came to Adele when he came back to school and took his breath away.

Adel has brown hair. She travels to the capital for work and accidentally ends up in the emperor's office by taking a magic door. In the room are huge stacks of papers - the emperor's paperwork, not bound books. The emperor begins speaking to her without looking up, thinking it was his assistant returning. His assistant actually returns while he's in the middle of talking, and then they notice Adel, but with her hair turned blonde. She's not exactly like the prince - the only change is to her hair color. She panicks and runs off, and the emperor is unable to locate her due to looking for an established magician with blonde hair, and no such person visited on that day.